# What is a rule to make target in Docker container?

Tags: docker, jenkins

To learn how to manipulate Docker images from within Jenkins, I am reading [this link](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/).

What is a "rule to make a target" in Docker? The simple example below is failing because there is "no rule to make a target". What does this mean in Docker?

### The Error And The Code That Triggers The Error

The `sh 'make test'` line of code in a Jenkinsfile from the link above is throwing an error when run inside the following block:

```
testImage.inside {
    sh "whoami"
    sh 'make test'
}
```

The actual error that Jenkins throws when trying to interpret the `sh 'make test'` line of code is:

```
make test— Shell Script<1s  
    [ple-dockere-containered-app-WWNVRTE6XFKMI4JPEVK2F2U3HOGDZICATW6XBFM2IQUW5PAG5FWA] Running shell script
    + make test
    make: *** No rule to make target 'test'.  Stop.
```

The complete `Jenkinsfile` is:

```
node {
    // Clean workspace before doing anything
    deleteDir()

    try {
        stage ('Clone') {
            checkout scm
        }
        stage ('Build') {

            def testImage = docker.build("test-image", "./app") 

            testImage.inside {
                sh "whoami"
                sh 'make test'
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILED'
        throw err
    }
}
```

Note that the `make test` command is being run **inside the container**.

Comment: Inside your container, do you have a makefile, and does it contain the `test` target?

Comment: (Pro-tip: it is worth going easy with requests for tutorials - as helpful as they can be, requests for off-site resources are off-topic here. We have traditionally had problems with people seeding requests for fake requirements so that a spammer can punt their material, and it got out of hand, so we had to close that down. It's best to ask people to put their material here anyway, to prevent broken links spoiling an answer in the future.)